# Get unique values from inputbox and paste into cell input from another inputbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple macro for getting unique values from ex "A2:A" and then pasting the output into ex "B2:B" but I would like to have an `inputbox` instead, so that I can choose where the non-unique values are and where I want the output to be pasted

The macro
:

````
Dim d As Object, c As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c = Range("A2:A" & lr)
For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
  d(c(i, 1)) = 1
Next i
Range("B2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
End Sub```
````

Comment: Not entire clear on what you are asking for. Are you saying you want 2 **input boxes** or 1? Response would be dependent on what you need. Also, when you say `..ex "A2:A"..`, what's **`ex`**?

Comment: What difficulty are you having with using input boxes?

Comment: @Zac Sorry, ex is example

I have tried editing the macro to include the input from inputboxes but I can't get the "unique list"-thing to work

I want it to make/get unique list from the input from inputbox A and then create that list in cells written in inputbox B

Say for example that column A has 250 values, where 150 of them are unique and I want a list of those 150 values in column B

When I run the macro I want to be able to write: Inputbox A: non-unique values are in: "A2:A" and make these unique and paste the results in Inputbox 2: choosing a place where I want the data